# Problems when printing lists inside RJournal template code chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using RStudio Version 0.99.896 and trying to compile an article which uses RJournal template (.Rmd). The thing is, whenever I try to compile a simple chunk like

````
```{r}
l = list(a = list(b = c(1,2)), b = c(3,4))
l$a 
l[[1]]$b
```
````

i get this awful output (in the .pdf):

```
\begin{Schunk} \begin{Sinput} l = list(a = list(b = c(1,2)), b = c(3,4)) l$a \end{Sinput} \be-
gin{Soutput} #> b > [ 1 ] 12
\textbackslash{}end\{Sinput\}
\begin{Soutput}
> [1] 1 2
\end{Soutput}
\textbackslash{}end\{Schunk\}
\textbackslash{}begin\{Schunk\}
\begin{Sinput}
```

I don't even have to use the problematic $ (dollar sign) to get this. Printing any list or object will do. For instance, this line

```
model = auto.arima(ipca)
```

prints

```
    \begin{Soutput} #> Series: ipca #> ARIMA(1,1,2)(0,0,1)[12]
#> #> Coefficients: #> ar1 ma1 ma2 sma1 #> 0.8259 -0.8128 -0.1339 0.1851 #> s.e. 0.0604
0.0816 0.0676 0.0896 #> #> sigmaˆ2 estimated as 21.04: log likelihood=-919.24 #> AIC=1848.48
AICc=1848.68 BIC=1867.21 \end{Soutput} \end{Schunk}
```

It's a mess. Does anyone know what's happening? Didn't see anyone else complaining about it. I guess it's a simple question, then.

Comment: that looks like latex which is supposed to be compiled into the pdf. What version R and knitr are you using?

Comment: @RichardTelford version 1.12.3